# Aligning the JButton and JLabel on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

I am trying to create a JFrame and in which I want the button (Select the Device) to be on top and a text message (Active) which is in the form of Label at the bottom. I am unable to do that and they are all coming up in the same line next to each other.

```
    JFrame f= new JFrame("AutoV");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(600,400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel p=new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(Color.gray);

    JButton b=new JButton("Select the Device");
    JLabel lab=new JLabel("Active");
    lab.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);

    //p.add(b);
    p.add(lab);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    f.add(p);
    Dimension dim1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    f.setLocation(dim1.width/2-f.getSize().width/2, dim1.height/2-f.getSize().height/2);
```

Comment: 1. JPanel has FLowLayout and 2. f.setVisible(true); must be last code line there, 3

Comment: The control location is controlled by the layout, which one did you use for th the canvas?

Comment: @RomanC The default layout, as @mKorbel said, is `FlowLayout` since the asker didn't set anything else. Also, there is no canvas in Swing :)

Comment: There is no canvas in this program. I just need to align the button and the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up different layouts. The default layout of many components is FlowLayout, witch just aligns all elements horizontally, and as small as possible. Setting the panels layout to box or grid layout should do the trick.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html